# Continuously parse CSV files which are updated by another process in PHP

Tags: php, html, django, csv

I'm working on project in which csv file is updated continuously with python program. 
I'm creating a dynamic webpage in PHP which shows updated csv values in HTML table. 
I got logic for reading csv file in PHP but don't know how to **read the updated values continuously** and **display them in HTML table** in which updated values overwrites the previous values

Comment: you can add this line <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30"> inside your <head> tag in your html file , it will refresh the page every 30 seconds. is this sufficient for you? php can't change current value by it self, you have to use javascript.

Comment: is there any way to link jQuery event-handler with PHP code.

Comment: please show a sample code so i can help you better, you will need 2 separate files, one html with js/jquery and a php file, the html file will call the php file to get new data with ajax